# What is the purpose of -5 in placeholder? c#

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array, placeholder

We've been creating a program where it has to show the table or array. I just want to know the purpose of -5 in the placeholder
`Console.Write("{0, -5}", Greater[row, col]);`

Comment: It specifies the precision and position of the number being formatted (I'm assuming that `Greater` is a 2-dimensional array of float, double or decimal (it would have been useful for you to show more context in you code, especially the types) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

-5 is a formatting specifier to determine the width of the output string for this placeholder

`5` means the string will be at least 5 chars wide (padded with spaces) and the `-` means the value produced by accessing the Greater array will be aligned to the left

If the value in Greater at that row,col is 1.2 the output will be `"1.2  "`

If the value were 1.23456789 the output would *not* be cut off at 5 wide. To ensure the data is formatted to a certain presentation you can add another formatting specifier after a colon, to dictate how the number will be formatted. For more info see "Control Spacing" onwards in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.format?view=net-5.0